# Any way to link Chat Api contacts (jid) with graph api user id with Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chat

I have a facebook chat application which has successfully populated a list of users online.

I want to be able to get the graph api userid of a specific user online using their jid.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to take the first part of the JID (the part before the @chat.facebook.com) and go to https://graph.facebook.com/FIRSTPART and you'll get the basic information (including user ID) for the user. For more on the Graph API, check out [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).